# Coloring line segments in altair

Tags: python, altair

How do I change the color of line segments in an altair plot? In my example, I want to color all line segments that are above 1 to red and below 1 to green. My current attempts look like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'y': [0.8, 0.9, 1.1, 1.0, 0.9]
})
alt.Chart(df).mark_line(
    point=True,
    line=True,
).encode(
    alt.X("x", type="quantitative"),
    alt.Y("y", type="quantitative"),
    color=alt.Color(
        condition={
            "test": "datum.y < 1",
            "value": "green"
        },
        value="red",
    ),
).save("plot.html")
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result]

Instead I want:

[image]

Comment: This is unfortunately not possible in Vega-Lite/Altair at the moment. I can't find the issue right now but there is an open one in the Vega-Lite repository tracking this. For now, you would need to create a second layer with the lines of the second color

Comment: @joelostblom Thanks! It's good to know that this doesn't work. I was playing around with second layer, but this led to two separate lines.

Comment: Yeah, you have to bridge the gap by adding additional end points to one of the layers manually in the data.